# VBA Vlookup error handling

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, vlookup

Does anybody know how to stop a vba vlookup code in the below format from giving "#N/A" errors?

I have 2 different workbooks. The first workbook is "current_sheet_name" where I want the number returned from the vlookup, and the second workbook is where I'm looking the values up from called "filename.csv". Not all of the values are contained in "filename.csv", so the vlookup code is returning errors for the names that are missing.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
Sub vlookupcode    

Dim soft_output As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current_sheet_name") 
soft_output = "D:\Data\[filename.csv]"
set rng1 = ws1.Range("$R$12:$R$19")

rng1 = "=vlookup($Q12,'" & soft_output & "filename_tab'!$A:$C,3,False)"

end sub
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: See answer from Doug Glancy at the link above

Answer (score 0):

wrap the formula in an `IFERROR` statement

```
rng1 = "=IFERROR(vlookup($Q12,'" & soft_output & "filename_tab'!$A:$C,3,False),What to display instead of an error)"
```

Of course, this will not work until you replace the text with an actual value
e.g. `""""` for an empty string
`""Not Found""` for a not found message
`0` for a zero value
etc.